# Meaning of "from my god it will depart"

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

What is the meaning of the sentence "from my god it will depart " mean ?

I found this in [a song of Nightwish "Sleeping sun"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/nightwish/sleepingsun.html) and I cannot understand it at all. I think it poetic but unfortunately my English literature and understanding of it is poor ...

Comment: It will depart from my god. **it** is the human heart, per @Rhythmatic's answer. The phrase "departing from God" can be a periphrasis for apostasy or wickedness.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it *is* poetic. I don't really understand the symbolism either, but I can at least help with the *meaning*.

The full verse is:

> Sorrow has a human heart
>   From my god it will depart

Which can be rewritten as a compound sentence like so:

> Sorrow has a human heart; from my god it will depart.

Since semicolons are the same thing as ", and" or ", but" let's swap that out:

> Sorrow has a human heart, and from my god it will depart.

Word order here is still weird. Let's fix that, too:

> Sorrow has a human heart, and it will depart from my god.

Aha! Now we can see that the "it" in the part you're asking about is referring specifically to "sorrow" from the previous line. "Sorrow will depart from my god."

I won't attempt to deconstruct the symbolism here, but I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Yeah sure I had the fix in my head but what does "God" mean here ?

Comment: @Tolaso It means god, a deity. I don't know what metaphor he's trying to make here, but I suppose it could be related to something holy or pure. Not sure. Poetry.

Answer (score 0):

or "
Sorrow has a human heart
From my god it will depart"

could just mean;

1. they are sad, but they are adamant that it will go away, or they will work on making it go away (the older people used to say "by God" in the same context people today say "so help me god, I will....."
2. or it could just mean "with the help of God the sadness I feel will go away"